# Databinding and Lists in instances of classes

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, datagrid

I have initialised an instance of a class i have called "Relation" this class also contains a list of "Bills". When i databind this information to a grid, the Relations are showing, tho the Bills ain't. The Relation information is returning in a List and the Bills are inside.

```
Relation cRelation = new Relation();
List<tRelation> relationList = cRelation.getRelations();
```

a relation has:

```
relation.Bills <== List<tBills>;
```

How to make sure that the list inside the list is also getting showed in the Datagrid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Use a Master/Detail approach for this, Here's one approach: [How to: Create Master/Detail Lists with the Windows Forms DataGrid Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/59y45529.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but i am using my own types, so i can't bind. I have to fill a new datagrid on my own then.

Answer (score 0):

Put a GridView inside an ItemTemplate of your grid.

On **RowDataBound** of your first grid, get the inner grid for each row and apply databinding from the source list as follows:

```
Relation relation = (Relation) e.Row.DataItem;
GridView grdInner = (GridView) e.Row.FindControl("grdInner");
grdInner.DataSource = relation.Bills;
grdInner.DataBind();
```